# Drag and Drop Media Not Working in Windows 10 Edge Browser

Tags: uploads, media, browser-compatibility

Since the release of Windows 10 and its new browser called Edge, I am now unable to drag and drop media to upload it on my WordPress website. Dragging and dropping media works fine on any other browser except for the Edge browser. Is there a work around for this or something?

Comment: The workaround is to use a different browser. [There is currently no drag/drop support.](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/8964523-support-html5-drag-and-drop-of-files-from-explorer)

Comment: Ok, I guess I will just have to settle with that until they fix it.